# Realm retrieving specific data

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, realm

Good Day! I started using Realm.io Database for iOS 3 days ago. I can store data from the app to the database. But Retrieving it gives me headache. My problem is i cannot select specific data on database. I'm using this to get the data

```
    RLMResults *data = [MapLocationCoordinates allObjects];
    NSString *rawData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[data objectAtIndex:0]];
    NSLog(@"%@",rawData);
```

Now the result:

```
2015-05-07 05:31:01.554 Sample App[2401:79922] MapLocationCoordinates {
    objectId = k0zpFLr5Un;
    fName = George;
    fLatitude = 11.985050;
    fLongitude = 121.925295;
}
```

How can i get the specific data i want? For example, the `fName` and `objectId`

Thanks for your answers! More power!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RLMResults` has many similar methods as `NSArray` and in some cases can be treated as such. For example, you can get the first object in the `RLMResults` using the `-firstObject` method.

In your code:

```
MapLocationCoordinates *coords = [data firstObject];
NSString *fName = [coords fName];
NSString *objectId = [coords objectId];
```

You can also iterate over an `RLMResults` collection in the same way as you would an array with `for(id obj in collection){}`.

Comment: It's working now. but Why only on the first row? how about the row below? Thanks!

Comment: If you want more than one row (using `firstObject` or `objectAtIndex:` etc), then you need to iterate through it like I described in my answer.