# Xcode - Recevier type 'BFTask' for instance message is forward declaration

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sqlite, core-data

I posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30098613/realm-retrieving-specific-data) question earlier.

But I didn't get what I want. Now I'm trying to use Parse and instead of saving it locally using Realm, I will be using CoreData or Sqlite.

But my problem is in BFTask.

I read their documentation in regards with saving the data locally using sqlite.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"GameScore"];
[query fromLocalDatastore];
[[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"xWMyZ4YEGZ"] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
  if (task.error) {
    // something went wrong;
    return task;
  }

  // task.result will be your game score
  return task;
}];
```

But I'm having an error on the BFTask Part.

It says `Recevier type 'BFTask' for instance message is forward declaration`

How can I fix this?

I already added the `CoreData.framework` to my project (of course) and also the `#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>` to my .pch file. and also in my .h and .m file but I still got the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you imported `BFTask.h`? Missing an import is the usual cause of this error.

Comment: where can i get that BFTask.h?

Comment: I have no idea, it's your code. I'm just explaining what usually causes that error.

Comment: BFTask i think is in xcode by default. It is not a custom class or something.

Comment: Some quick Googling shows that it's part of Parse's Bolts framework: https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-iOS You'll need to include it from there.

Comment: Thanks! It's fixed now. I just added `#import <Bolts/Bolts.h>` in my .m file.

Answer (score 1):

Put `#import <Bolts/Bolts.h>` at the top of your file.